# Is this form of initialization for arrays valid?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

The following code only compiles in clang AFAIK:

```
struct A { 
  char x[4]; 
  A():x("bug") { } 
};

int main()
{
    char x[4] ("bug");
}
```

But according to this [gcc bug report](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43453) it is valid code and was fixed for a later version of GCC (someone should report it to Microsoft as well then.)

The justification for fixing this bug is:

§ 8.5/13

> The form of initialization (using parentheses or =) is generally
>   insignificant, but does matter when the initializer or the entity
>   being initialized has a class type; see below. If the entity being
>   initialized does not have class type, the *expression-list* in a
>   parenthesized initializer shall be a single expression.

Initialization of `char` arrays with string literals are covered in § 8.5.2, which only shows an example using an equals sign. Since this kind of initialization is different from other kinds, is this code valid by the standard?

Comment: Was fixed, not will be fixed.

Comment: Examples are not normative, and I can't find any restriction in 8.5.2 or 8.5/17 which forbids using direct-initialization.

Comment: @Deduplicator: was fixed *in trunk*.  The fix will be released with GCC 5.x.

Comment: Also, ICC 13 on [Godbolt](http://gcc.godbolt.org) accepts the OPs code with `--std=c++11`

Answer (score 1):

It is valid. It has been since C++98. In C++11, [dcl.init]/16 governs direct-initialization:

> [...]
>
> - If the initializer is a (non-parenthesized) *braced-init-list*, the object or reference is list-initialized (8.5.4).
> - If the destination type is a reference type, see 8.5.3.
> - If the destination type is an array of characters, an array of `char16_t`, an array of `char32_t`, or an array of `wchar_t`, and the initializer is a string literal, see 8.5.2.

Section 8.5.2 [dcl.init.string] explains how the initialization is done:

> A `char` array (whether plain `char`, `signed char`, or `unsigned char`), `char16_t` array, `char32_t` array, or `wchar_t` array can be initialized by a narrow character literal, `char16_t` string literal, `char32_t` string
> literal, or wide string literal, respectively, or by an appropriately-typed string literal enclosed in braces.
> Successive characters of the value of the string literal initialize the elements of the array. [*Example:* ...]
>
> There shall not be more initializers than there are array elements. [*Example:* ...]
>
> If there are fewer initializers than there are array elements, each element not explicitly initialized shall be zero-initialized (8.5).

There's no indication that only copy-initialization is allowed. Though, it is true that the examples only show copy-initialization.

The OP has provided no reason to believe that it's not allowed, other than that GCC apparently used to not accept it, and the developers acknowledged that it's a bug. Which, really, should be viewed as reason to believe that it is allowed.